# How to use DAY function in PostgreSQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, datepart

I have this query for MySQL database:

```
Article.where('DAY( created_at ) = DAY( ? )', day)
```

And I try to use the query above also in the PostgreSQL database, specifically I am trying something like this:

```
Article.where("DATE_PART('day', created_at) = DATE_PART('day', ?)", today)
```

But I am getting the error `PGError: ERROR:  function date_part(unknown, unknown) is not unique`

Why is there that error? I thought I have the syntax by documentation...

Comment: Programmers should know always to include the version numbers. Many functions have only been introduced in recent versions or PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `today` is a string of the pattern `YYYY-MM-DD`. You could just extract the rightmost two characters, instead of casting to date and then extracting a number. Would be faster and simpler:

```
Article.where("date_part('day', created_at::date)::int
                        = right(?, 2)::int", today)
```

[`right()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) requires PostgreSQL 9.1 or later. In older version you can subsitute:

```
... = substring(?, 9)
```

Because you want characters 9 and 10.

---

This should work, too:

```
Article.where("date_part('day', created_at::date)::int
                        = date_part('day', ?::date)", today)
```

Note, that you must cast `'2012-01-16'` to `date`, not to `interval`. `'2012-01-16'::interval` would be nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/functions-datetime.html) there are two functions:

- `date_part(text, timestamp)`
- `date_part(text, interval)`

so database cannot choose which one you want. Cast the second parameter to timestamp, e.g. like this:

```
DATE_PART('day', created_at::interval) = DATE_PART('day', ?::interval)
```

Comment: I still can't find the way to use it... `today` variable is in the shape `2012-01-16`, `created_at` column is the type `datetime`, but I am still getting an errors, I tried already million ways to possibilities to the query